# Cocos2d CCSprite moves with CCLayer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

I recently bought an iOS game and currently I am changing graphics and adding new things.
Here is my problem: I have a player which jumps from one object to another. When he jumps the camera follows the movement and all CCSprites that I've added to the GameScene also move with the camera. In other words I am adding sprites to a layer which moves and they also moves. How can I make the sprites not to move with the camera ? The are levels and they are loaded from svg file.

Comment: don't add the sprites to the layer that is moving

Comment: When I added to another layer i cannot see it

Comment: Check the order of your layers. Make sure the sprite you're adding is not on a layer that's under another one.

Comment: Your sprite is added in layer so that it move with layer